# Probability of Sum Being Greater than $12$ of $3$ non-random discrete variables.

Tags: probability, statistics

*(Preface: This question is based on one aspect of this year's **[FIRST Robotics Competition](https://www.firstinspires.org/robotics/frc)**.)*

This question pertains to predicting the likelihood of **three** teams (in an alliance) having a combined total of at least $n$ points, based on how all three of the teams have performed in previous matches.  In any previous match, a team will score a **discrete**, and independent, number of points, normally with $0 \leq n \leq 6$.  For example, there may be a team that has scored points $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ in their previous matches.

What I want to figure out is the probability that an alliance of    **three** teams will have a combined score greater than 12 in any given match (three teams in a match is the alliance).  I have previously thought about this in a few ways, such as using the average of the previously scored points, the standard deviation of the previously scored points, and the max of the previously scored points.

In the case that my previous explanation wasn't clear, let me provide an example.  Let the number of points that team $A$ has scored in each of their 5 previous matches be $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.  Now, let's say we also have team $B$, and they have scored $\{4,4,4,4,4\}$ points in each of their previous 5 matches.  Lastly, we have team $C$, and they scored $\{6,5,6,6,5\}$ points in each of their previous matches.  As an alliance of teams $A$, $B$, and $C$, what is the probability that the sum of their scores is greater than $12$?

I am hoping that someone can point me in the correct direction as to how to solve this.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-random"? If the scores are not random, then what are they?

Comment: Well, a team has the ability to score a certain number of points.  If they score 5 points in 3 matches straight, they most likely will not score 0 in their next match (as they have shown that they are consistently scoring in the range of 5 points). However, there is no guarantee they will score 5 points. They could score 4 points or even 3 points (unlikely due to their previous data). But, none of this is random.

Comment: As for the distribution of the scores, I would assume that they are pretty close to a normal distribution. (The example of a team that scores 0,1,2,3, and 4 points might be a bad example because teams do not perform that inconsistently in general).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "none of this is random".  When I roll a die, the only faces that can come up are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6, but which one comes up on any particular roll is random.  How is your problem different? What makes it not random?

Comment: If a team scores 5 points in a match, it requires a certain amount of "skill."  In the next match, they will most likely score near that amount, as they have shown that they have the skill level to score that many points. They won't lose all of their skill and score 1 point.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean that their scores are not random.  If a team scores a 5, you might suppose that there is a 50% chance that they will next score a 5 and a 50% chance that they will next score a 4; in this case, the score will be either 4 or 5 but which one it will be is random.

Answer (score 1):

If we simply use the five values to estimate the probabilities, then we can get a probability distribution for each possible score for each team and then determine the probability distribution of the sum from those distributions.

Using your example, team A has a probability of $1/5$ each of scoring $0, 1, 2, 3,$ and $4$. We can represent this distribution with the generating function
$$
\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}x+\frac{1}{5}x^2+\frac{1}{5}x^3+\frac{1}{5}x^4.
$$ 
Team B is guaranteed to score $4$, so its generating function is simply
$$
x^4
$$
and team C has a $2/5$ probability of scoring $5$ and $3/5$ probability of scoring $6$, so its generating function is
$$
\frac{2}{5}x^5+\frac{3}{5}x^6.
$$
The product of these generating functions will give us the distribution of the sum of these three scores:
$$
\frac{3}{25} x^{14}
 + \frac{1}{5} x^{13}
 + \frac{1}{5} x^{12}
 + \frac{1}{5} x^{11}
 + \frac{1}{5} x^{10}
 + \frac{2}{25} x^9
$$
From this we can conclude that the probability of scoring greater than $12$ is $\frac{3}{25}+\frac{1}{5}=\frac{8}{25}$.

Now, this is all based on estimating the probability of each team's score by using the empirically determined values: the probability is simply the number of times that score has occurred divided by the number of games.  This is probably not the best estimate: for example, a team that has scored from $3$s and some $5$s, but no $4$s is probably likely to score $4$ some time in the future, but the method I used here treats the probability of a $4$ by this team as zero.  To use estimate the probabilities any other way, you would need more information about how the scores are distributed.